# Parquet bytes dataframe to UTF-8 in Spark

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to read a dataframe from a parquet file with Spark in python but my dataframe is byte encoded so when I use spark.read.parquet and then df.show() it looks like the following:

```
    +---+----------+----+
    | C1|        C2|  C3|
    +---+----------+----+
    |  1|[20 2D 2D]|   0|
    |  2|[32 30 31]|   0|
    |  3|[43 6F 6D]|   0|
    +---+----------+----+
```

As you can see it the values are converted to hexadecimal values... I've read the entire documentation of spark dataframes but I did not found anything. Is it possible to convert to UTF-8?

The df.printSchema() output:

```
 |-- C1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- C2: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- C3: long (nullable = true)
```

The Spark version is 2.4.4

Thank you!

Comment: probably just `F.col('C2').astype('string')` (untested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `binary` type column, which is like a `bytearray` in python. You just need to cast to string:

```
df = df.withColumn("C2", df["C2"].cast("string"))
df.show()
#+---+---+---+
#| C1| C2| C3|
#+---+---+---+
#|  1| --|  0|
#|  2|201|  0|
#|  3|Com|  0|
#+---+---+---+
```

Likewise in python:

```
str(bytearray([0x20, 0x2D, 0x2D]))
#' --'
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you so much. It would be fine if they had some method or parameter to decode the entire dataframe without casting.